# SFINAE with C++14 return type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++14

Thanks to C++14, we'll soon be able to curtail verbose trailing return types; such as the generic `min` example from David Abrahams 2011 [post](http://web.archive.org/web/20130820172127/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/11/having-it-all-pythy-syntax/):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto min(T x, U y)
    -> typename std::remove_reference< decltype(x < y ? x : y) >::type
{ return x < y ? x : y; }
```

Under C++14 the return type can be omitted, and `min` can be written as:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto min(T x, U y)
{ return x < y ? x : y; }
```

This is a simple example, however return type deduction is very useful for generic code, and can avoid much replication. My question is, for functions such as this, how do we integrate SFINAE techniques? For example, how can I use `std::enable_if` to restrict our `min` function to return types which are integral?

Answer (score 12):

You can't SFINAE the function using the return type if you're using return type deduction. This is mentioned in the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html)

> Since the return type is deduced by instantiating the template, if the instantiation is ill-formed, this causes an error rather than a substitution failure.

You can, however, use an extra, unused template parameter to perform SFINAE.

```
template <class T, class U>
auto min1(T x, U y)
{ return x < y ? x : y; }

template <class T, class U,
          class...,
          class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value &&
                                   std::is_integral<U>::value>>
auto min2(T x, U y)
{
    return x < y ? x : y; 
}

struct foo {};

min1(foo{}, foo{}); // error - invalid operands to <
min1(10, 20);

min2(foo{}, foo{}); // error - no matching function min2
min2(10, 20);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8379c6d205210105)

Comment: Not to mention `std::is_integal_v`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 [Looks like](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8379c6d205210105) gcc-4.9's libstdc++ has `enable_if_it`. I'll definitely be using it more often now. With gcc-4.8 I never used it because I didn't want to change coliru's command line too much between clang and gcc :)

Comment: @chris I can't get the helper templates for `::value` to work on coliru with either gcc or clang.

Comment: @Praetorian, libc++ has it implemented. Try `-stdlib=libc++` with `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` in addition to `main.cpp`.

Comment: I am aware of this use of SFINAE, my suggestion was that the *return type* would form the SFINAE condition - not the arguments: for built-in types the return type will be the type of one of the arguments, but not for user types. I was also only giving `min` as an example. It seems unfortunate that the inferred returned type is destined to elude our grasp. I believe we have not seen the end of trailing return decltype code replication.

Comment: More trivially, with `min2`, there is still the chance that the hoof-handed hacker could still resort to an honest `min2<int,float,void>(10,3.142f)`.

Comment: Thankyou for the link and quote from the proposal.

Comment: @user2023370 Unfortunately this is what you have with return type deduction. And I prefer the SFINAE with an unused parameter over the return type for functions that are user facing, just so they don't have to dig through a `decltype` or `enable_if` expression to figure out what the type is, but you can argue that's what documentation is for. Anyway, there is a solution to someone providing an explicit third template argument ... more unused parameters :) See the updated answer; with the addition of parameter pack, you won't be able to provide an argument to the parameter doing the SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful remarks. I'd forgotten about that use of a parameter pack, to prevent the third argument, so thanks again. It seems as if the solution you present is still better for SFINAE on the argument types rather than the return type. In my first `min` example from Dave Abrahams, we're only dealing with the very small `x < y ? x : y`. Alas, code excerpts such as this still seem to be necessary when working with the return type.