# SFINAE constexpr with std::get

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, sfinae

This is a follow-up question to [Detecting constexpr with SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232758/detecting-constexpr-with-sfinae).

I want to detect if an element of a tuple (or anything which can be used with `std::get`) is constexpr. So I wrote the following helpers similar to what Xeo gave:

```
template<size_t> struct sfinae_true : std::true_type{};

template<size_t N, class T>
auto check(const T& arg) -> sfinae_true<(std::get<N>(arg),N)>;

template<size_t N, class>
std::false_type check(...);
```

Now my test driver code:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr std::tuple<size_t, size_t> arg(4,5);
    typedef decltype(check<0,decltype(arg)>(arg)) is_cexpr;
    std::cout << "is constexpr? " << is_cexpr::value << '\n';
}
```

However, this always prints out `false` for me! To check that for some reason the false overload isn't always being called, I commented out the false overload and get the compiler error:

> note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with N = 0, T = const std
>   ::tuple]: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
>   auto check(const T& arg) -> sfinae_true<(std::get(arg),0)>;

However, I do know that I can call `std::get<N>(arg)` and get a constexpr value:

```
template<size_t N>
class A{};

int main()
{
    constexpr std::tuple<size_t, size_t> arg(4,5);
    A<std::get<0>(arg)> a_val;
}
```

This compiles just fine.

- Why does the check function not detect the constexpr-ness correctly?
- How do I fix this?

I tested this with Clang 3.8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

**edit:**

As a further test based on Sam's answer, I tried the form:

```
template<size_t N, class T>
auto check(const T& arg)
{
    return sfinae_true<(std::get<N>(arg)*0)>();
}
```

This gets rid of the comma operator entirely, which GCC 5.4.0 compiles just fine, but Clang 3.8.0 still complains about. Interestingly, Clang highlights that `arg` itself is not constexpr.

Why is this problematic still? What are the rules for constexpr function arguments?

Comment: Issue is that `arg` parameter is not `constexpr`...

Comment: (To expand slightly on what I think @Jarod42 means: `arg` being a function parameter is never considered as a constant expression, even if the argument you provide to the function is a constant expression.)

Comment: How would I detect if the result of a function call would be constexpr if this method doesn't work? Clearly I can use the tuple as a constexpr value by constructing the `a_val` object.

Comment: @helloworld922: `constexpr int f(const std::tuple<int>& t) {A<std::get<0>(t)> a_val; return 0;}` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a compiler issue.

```
template<size_t N, class T>
auto check(const T& arg) -> sfinae_true<(std::get<N>(arg),N)>;
```

gcc fails to compile this:

> t.C:8:61: error: template argument 1 is invalid  auto check(const T&
>   arg) -> sfinae_true<(std::get(arg),N)>;

But after tweaking this slightly, I get the expected results with gcc 6.1.1:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t> struct sfinae_true : std::true_type{};

template<size_t N, class T>
auto check(const T& arg)
{
    return sfinae_true<(std::get<N>(arg),N)>();
}

template<size_t N, class>
std::false_type check(...);

int main()
{
    constexpr std::tuple<size_t, size_t> arg(4,5);
    typedef decltype(check<0,decltype(arg)>(arg)) is_cexpr;
    std::cout << "is constexpr? " << is_cexpr::value << '\n';
}
```

This results in:

```
is constexpr? 1
```

Note that commas weren't allowed in constant expressions pre-C++11. Might be something left over from that era...

Comment: I tried your tweak in clang 3.8.0 and it doesn't work, but it does with GCC 5.4.0. Interestingly, the part which clang highlights as being non-constexpr is not the comma operator, but the fact that `arg` is non-constexpr (I tested this by removing the comma operator).

Comment: The mandated behaviour is different in your version. SFINAE does not apply to deduced return types; SFINAE is in the immediate context only whereas return type deduction requires a rather deep instantiation of the function template.

Comment: Interestingly enough, @dyp, the end result is the intended result. A non-constexpr parameter did not result in a compilation error, but the expected default template. It looks to me like the template function's return type is deduced at declaration time, and then participates in SFINAE resolution normally.

Comment: clang++4.0 refuses to compile your program, though. And gcc reports 1 whether or not `arg` is `constexpr`.

Comment: Please see http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#11 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/24396819