# C++ template selection - unusual case

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following defintions

```
  template <typename T1, typename T2> class ArithmeticType {
  public:
    T1 x1;
    T2 x2;
    typedef typeof(x1+x2) Type;
  };

  template <typename D1, typename D2> inline
    std::complex<typename ArithmeticType<D1,D2>::Type>
    operator+(const std::complex<D1>& x1, const std::complex<D2>& x2) {
    D1 x1r = real(x1);
    D1 x1i = imag(x1);
    D2 x2r = real(x2);
    D2 x2i = imag(x2);
    return std::complex<typename ArithmeticType<D1,D2>::Type>(x1r+x2r, x1i+x2i);
  }
```

I then use this class as follows

```
    std::complex<double> x;
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
    ArithmeticType<std::complex<double>,std::complex<float>>::Type y;
    std::cout << typeid(y).name() << std::endl;
```

which the produces output

```
St7complexIdE
St7complexIdE
```

which makes sense to me:  `y` is of type `std::complex<double>`

Now, with the indent of adding complex and floating types, I add a specialization of the `operator+` template so the code becomes

```
  template <typename T1, typename T2> class ArithmeticType {
  public:
    T1 x1;
    T2 x2;
    typedef typeof(x1+x2) Type;
  };

  template <typename D1, typename D2> inline
    std::complex<typename ArithmeticType<D1,D2>::Type>
    operator+(const std::complex<D1>& x1, const std::complex<D2>& x2) {
    D1 x1r = real(x1);
    D1 x1i = imag(x1);
    D2 x2r = real(x2);
    D2 x2i = imag(x2);
    return std::complex<typename ArithmeticType<D1,D2>::Type>(x1r+x2r, x1i+x2i);
  }

  template <typename D1, typename D2> inline
    std::complex<typename ArithmeticType<D1,D2>::Type>
    operator+(const std::complex<D1>& x1, const D2 x2) {
    D1 x1r = real(x1);
    D1 x1i = imag(x1);
    return std::complex<typename ArithmeticType<D1,D2>::Type>(x1r+x2, x1i+x2);
  }
```

I run the same code as before but now I get a compile error because the compiler tries to use the second specialization instead of the first.   This doesn't make sense to me.  I would think that the (g++) compiler would still choose the first specialization.

Can some explain the rule why this occurs?

Comment: Heads-up: `typeof` is non-standard. You should use `decltype` in its place.

Comment: How do you invoke operator+? What error code do you get?

Comment: @IgorR. I use `ArithmeticType<std::complex<double>,std::complex<float>>::Type y;`   which works in the first case, but then when I add the second template specialization it tries to use the second template and fails.  See the error explanation given below by @divinas

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are observing behavior caused by this quote from [cppreference/SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

> Only the failures in the types and expressions in the **immediate context of the function type** or its template parameter types are SFINAE errors. If the evaluation of a substituted type/expression causes a side-effect such as instantiation of some template specialization, generation of an implicitly-defined member function, etc, errors in those side-effects are treated as **hard errors**.

A minimal example:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_foo
{
   using foo_t = decltype(T{}.foo());
};

template <typename T> void f(T&&) { }

// SFINAE error => no compilation error:
template <typename T> decltype(T{}.foo()) f(T&&) { }

// non-SFINAE error => hard error:
template <typename T> typename has_foo<T>::foo_t f(T&&) { }

int main()
{
   f(1);
}
```

Your code basically behaves the same, just instead of `has_foo` you have `ArithmeticType`.

---

As for the return type deduction with `auto`, see, for example: [SFINAE with C++14 return type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24396819/580083).

A working example with the same `has_foo` as above:

```
#ifndef DEFINE_THIS_SYMBOL_TO_CAUSE_COMPILATION_ERROR
void f(int) { }
#endif

// no SFINAE => viable candidate
template <typename T> auto f(T&&)
{
   return typename has_foo<T>::foo_t{};
}

int main()
{
   f(1);
}
```

If `void f(int) { }` is defined, its a better match and the templated `f` is not instantiated.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly.  In my case, it is not that the compiler chooses the second templated specialization over the first, it is that during the decision-making process an error is encountered as a side-effect of evaluating the second templated specialization.

Comment: While researching i found the same (and you managed to explain it better than I did).
I still don't get the auto case though. I thought the auto return type is evaluated in a non-immediate context - why doesn't this cause a Hard error?

Comment: @divinas I guess that with `auto`, the return type is not evaluated at all unless a corresponding function definition is selected as the best candidate.

Comment: That's what my guess was as well, but couldn't find any document supporting that guess (nor contradicting it either) :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the second template is the deduction of the return value:

```
template <typename D1, typename D2> inline
std::complex<typename ArithmeticType<D1,D2>::Type>
operator+(const std::complex<D1>& x1, const D2 x2)
```

When you try to instantiate `ArithmeticType<std::complex<double>, std::complex<float> >`

The second `operator+` types are deduced to:
D1: `double`, D2: `std::complex<float>`. You then try to instantiate `ArithmeticType` with `D1=double`, `D2=std::complex<float>`. This in turn, tries to deduce the type of `operator+` for a `double` and `std::complex<float>`. There is no such function, and you fail to compile.

Comment: But why does it use the second template and not the first?  The second template compiles fine for other code, such as
`ArithmeticType<std::complex<double>,float>::Type`

Comment: I believe this is happening while selecting the viable candidates. Because operator+ is overloaded, both of them are deemed viable. In order to decide which one of them would be used (it should be the more specialized one, if it has less type conversions necessary), the whole function signature must be known.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you declare the return type to be auto, this seems to compile fine. I'm still trying to figure out why exactly, will update my answer once I find out.